# Regex expression for phone validation - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to have phone validation like `cccc xxx xxx xxxx`. Where `cccc` is a country code and can be 0 to 9. `x` is a phone number. I tried with the below regex but it is not working when only 10 number are given.

`/^\d{1,4}?[- ]?(?:\([2-9]\d{2}\)\ ?|[2-9]\d{2}(?:\-?|\ ?))[2-9]\d{2}[- ]?\d{4}$/`

It should take a value from 10 to 14 numbers.

Comment: A list of valid and invalid number will be helpful.

Comment: `d{1,4}?` means `between 1 and 4 times`, therefore zero digits is not allowed. Use `d{0,4}?`

Comment: It is not possible to create a validation to a phone number to all countries. This is because there is no defined pattern. Each country has its specificities. There are countless threads here on that and all is conclusive about validation to all countries.

Comment: Though you can define a pattern to use and HOPE that no one with a different pattern use your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the `1` in `/^\d{1,4}` to `0`, as `1` says you need atleast 1 occurance:-

```
^\d{0,4}?[- ]?(?:([2-9]\d{2})\ ?|[2-9]\d{2}(?:-?|\ ?))[2-9]\d{2}[- ]?\d{4}$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`/^(\d{1,4})?([-\s]?\d{3}){2}[-\s]?\d{4}$/`